# Not able to clear development log file when server running locahost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3

I am facing weird issue, where I am unable to clear development log file contents while server web-brick up and running.

But same works fine in **sublime text 2** editor ie. Clearing of development log file. This issue forcing me to restart server each and every time when I have to clear logs.

Kindly help me to avoid restarting for clearing logs. If any suggestions for workaround appreciated.

**EDIT :**

Observed issue with platforms **windows 7 64/32 bit , windows 10 64bit**(Checked on only these).

[image]

I have opened same log file with ST2 and ST3.

[image]

And tried to clear log file in ST2 and ST3, got alert message only in ST3.

[image]

For me it seems, its issue with Sublime Text 3, which is not allowing clearing of logs if used by other process.

**EDIT 2 :**

This is exactly the [issue](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-3-cant-save-locked-file-but-notepad-can/13130), I am facing right now.

Comment: What platform is this on? On a Mac I just delete the file, so maybe it's an o/s file locking thing.

Comment: I have observed issue with windows 7 64/32 bit , windows 10 64bit. On the log file we cant modify content or delete file as a whole as windows through the error saying "Used by another process"

Comment: This may be nothing to do with Rails or Sublime then, simply an issue with being able to modify a file on Windows that another process is writing to.

Comment: I am able to clear logs on stopping web brick server. That means Its issues with Rails and ST3 only. As I already mentioned everything just works fine if I use ST2 for same rails application.